# tns resources generate won't work properly

Tags: tns

I use this line of code to change app icon:

`tns resources generate icons file.png`

it works! the installed app icon changes.
**BUT** when I go to the ***recent menu*** or for the ***app.apk*** file itself still that default **{N}** icon appears.

How can I replace that icon once and for all?

[image: It Has been Changed Here!]

[image: But It is still There!]

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the actual problem is related to my smartphone itself!
somehow MIUI caches the icon and refuses to update it by new installations,

any way changing `id` in `nativescript.confi.ts` can solve the problem :|